# Newtype with Tuple

Tags: haskell, newtype

About this code from [LearnYouaHaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#the-newtype-keyword):

```
newtype Pair b a = Pair {getPair :: (a,b)}
instance Functor (Pair c) where
  fmap f (Pair (x, y)) = Pair (f x, y)
```

I understand that the first line creates a new data type from tuple. However, why does the order of arguments switched from `Pair b a` to `getPair :: (a,b)`? If I switch one of the order, then I get an error due to pattern matching in the definition of `fmap`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Functor` class requires a single type argument, while the `Pair` type has two. The instance definition for `Pair`:

```
instance Functor (Pair c) where ...
```

fixes the first type argument, which corresponds to the second element of the tuple. This means that `fmap` transforms the first element of the tuple. If the type arguments for `Pair` were in the other order, you would transform the second tuple element instead and the definition would have to change to:

```
fmap f (Pair (x, y)) = Pair (x, f y)
```

note the built-in definition for `Functor` on pairs already behaves this way e.g.

```
import Data.Functor
fmap (+1) ("first", 3)
```